# How can i add scrollling pagination using jquery?

Tags: jquery

i want to add scrolling pagination, as my scroller moves to the bottom of the page next page should be loaded. i found some results from internet but it doesn't works on a popup.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 313) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Replace window with modal wrapper view and document with scrolling view.

Comment: my wrapper view and scrolling view is same, its not working
$('#SearchProductsByCategory').scrollTop() >= $('#SearchProductsByCategory').height() - $('#SearchProductsByCategory').height()

Comment: It shouldnt be the same. Replicate your problem in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and share it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Intersection Observer (IO)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

You place a div (or any element really) on the bottom of your list and once this div is getting visible you load new elements and then you move the element back to the end of the list. First you have to set the options for your IO:

```
var options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

Here we set up the Observer to say once the element we watch is 100% visible we trigger a callback function.
Once the observer is set up, you need to say which element it should watch:

```
<div id="loadNewList"> </div> <-- div at end of list -->

var target = document.querySelector('#loadNewList');
observer.observe(target);
```

And last we say what should happen once the element is fully visible:

```
var callback = function(entries, observer) { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // Here you move the div (loadNewList) to the bottom and load the new page
  });
};
```